# Stereo calibration real world coordinate mathematics

Tags: math, opencv, matrix, geometry, stereoscopy

I have implemented the Stereo 3D example provided in book Learning OpenCV. Now I want to calculate the real world coordinates for the pixel that I have clicked on the left image. In this post I have came accross with the formula:

Pc = [R|t] * Pw where Pc and Pw are cam and world coordinates, R is rotation matrix and t is translation vector.

I have calculated the [R|T] part but how do I calculate Pw from this equation and How do I build the Pc? Should I just consider the 1x3 matrix containing [pixelx,pixely,0] ?

Thanks for any help!!!

Comment: You can't get 3D from a single point on the left image. You have to find the corresponding point on the right image, compute the disparity, then triangulate in 3D. Look at opencv's triangulatePoints http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#triangulatepoints projPoints1 are points in the left image, projPoint2 are points in the right image